# Sequences strictly decreasing to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive integers such that $\sin x_n$ strictly decreases to 0. Is it true that $\sqrt[n]{\sin x_n}\to 1$?

Comment: $x_n = n^{-n}$ says no.

Comment: @DanielFischer But $n^{-n}$ is rarely "a positive integer", is it?

Comment: @Did It isn't for $n > 1$. But you have to take my word for it or not, since it was during the grace period: when I wrote that comment neither the word integer, nor $\sin$ appeared in the question.

Comment: @DanielFischer You know what? Somehow, I do (believe you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If$\let\leq\leqslant$ we can bound $|\sin x_n|$ from above by something like $2^{-n}$, the limit of $\sqrt[n]{\sin x_n}$ will be at most $\frac12$. It would suffice to find an integer sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\in[2k_n\pi,2k_n\pi+2^{-n}]$ for some integer sequence $(k_n)$. Why? Because $\sin x\leq x$ for $x>0$, meaning that $\sin x_n\leq\sin2^{-n}\leq2^{-n}$, once we have our sequence.

It remains to show that such intervals containg an integer exist.

Note that $\pi$ is irrational. (If you don't want to use this fact, it's not very hard to find a solution for the case $\pi$ wouldn't be.) This means the set of fractional parts of integer multiples of $\pi$ is dense in $[0,1]$. So certainly we can find a decreasing sequence satisfying $x_n\in[2k_n\pi,2k_n\pi+2^{-n}]$ for every $n$, as desired.

Comment: In fact this inequality is true for all $x>0$.

Comment: Curiously, wolfram alpha seems to suggest that $\lim_n\sqrt[n]{|\sin n|}=1$. In your case $(x_n)$ need not be integers.

Comment: @Mailer Yes, the values of $n$ for which $\sin n<2^{-k}$ (as I used in my answer) are very rare for large $k$. Nonetheless there is an infinitude of them, allowing us to construct a counterexample.

Comment: No, because $x_n$ are not integers. This is not a valid counter-example.

Comment: It is, but I'm not just choosing arbirtary intervals of the form $[2k_n\pi,2k_n\pi+2^{-n}]$. I choose the intervals of this type that contain an integer.